# defining variables in shaders that may be used in code

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am defining some variables in my custom shader:

```
 _Emiss("emission", Float) = .5
 _Albed("albedo", Float) = .9
```

all is good till here, but when i try to use the variables in code:

```
void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
          o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * _Albed;
          o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * _Emiss;
      }
```

i get some errors telling me that _Albed and _Emiss are not declared.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is the shader in full:

```
Shader "Custom/cubemapReflShader" {


        Properties {
      _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "red" {}
      _Cube ("Cubemap", CUBE) = "" {}
      _Emiss("emission", Float) = .5
      _Albed("albedo", Float) = .9
      // _RefrColor ("Refraction color", Color)  = (.34, .85, .92, 1) // color
    }



    SubShader {
      Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
      CGPROGRAM
      #pragma surface surf Lambert
      struct Input {
          float2 uv_MainTex;
          float3 worldRefl;
      };
      sampler2D _MainTex;
      samplerCUBE _Cube;
      void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
          o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * .9;
          o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * .5;
      }
      ENDCG
    } 
    Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you [declare them to the shader](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/SL-PropertiesInPrograms.html) outside of properties?

```
Properties 
{
    _Emiss("emission", Float) = .5
    _Albed("albedo", Float) = .9
}

float _Emiss;
float _Albed;

void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
    o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * _Albed;
    o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * _Emiss;
}
```

**Update**

Modifying the OP's full script:

```
Shader "Custom/cubemapReflShader" {
    Properties {
  _MainTex ("Texture", 2D) = "red" {}
  _Cube ("Cubemap", CUBE) = "" {}
  _Emiss("emission", Float) = .5
  _Albed("albedo", Float) = .9
}
SubShader {
  Tags { "RenderType" = "Opaque" }
  CGPROGRAM
  #pragma surface surf Lambert
  struct Input {
      float2 uv_MainTex;
      float3 worldRefl;
  };
  sampler2D _MainTex;
  samplerCUBE _Cube;

  // PUT THESE HERE <----------
  float _Albed;
  float _Emiss;

  void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutput o) {
      o.Albedo = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex).rgb * _Albed;
      o.Emission = texCUBE (_Cube, IN.worldRefl).rgb * _Emiss;
  }
  ENDCG
} 
Fallback "Diffuse"
}
```

Comment: i've included my shader in full in the post

Comment: @BadescuAlexandru ?? Based on the shader you added to your post you did not add the floats I included in my example.  See my update.

Comment: i did try the variables declaration (i didn't put the code with the shaders including the varibles declared because it didn't work). It works now. I was adding the variables outside the subshader. Though it was something global, but your code works just great!